# Error uploading applications, android studio after update

Tags: android, android-studio

Error uploading applications after update android studio.

Hello, I have a serious problem, I can not change any of my applications, android 2.0 update after.
When you upload the app in play store, I get the message appears apk is not aligned.

I had never had this problem, I have tried using zipaling.exe but still does not work.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the correct file?

Comment: If it is correct, I have also tried other different app, even when creating a new app also happens the same.